How to test that MYSQL-Connector-Python is working correctly?
Situation
I am trying to troubleshoot my issue between Python and MYSQL. I have found myself in a situation where I am temporarily forced to develop on a Windows 11 machine. I am not sure if that is why I am experiencing problems as I have never had an issue on the *NIX machine. I am using MYSQL 8.0.40 and Python 3.13 64bit natively with MYSQL-Connector-Python installed via PIP.
Problem
When I try to connect and create, edit, view databases or tables I get no errors but I get no action either. Basically, I have confirmed that I can connect to MYSQL from Python but it appears no SQL statements execute.
Actions
I installed MYSQL from the MS Installer and Python without issue. I installed the connector using pip install mysql-connector-python without problem.
I am using the test example to connect to an existing DB using this:
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='pass',
                              host='localhost',
                              database='testdb')

cnx.close()

When I run the script, there are no errors so I assume it works. I experimented with changing the host using various IPs and got timeout errors back so I assume it is connecting.
I then tried to create a new DB using the following:
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="yourusername",
  password="yourpassword"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE mydatabase") 

There are no errors but no DB gets created. I've tried this with an existing DB and created a table with no success. I have checked permissions, and I have used MYSQL root user and an admin user with full rights.
Troubleshooting
How can I see what is happening? For example is there a log that might explain what is happening here. Is this a common problem around permissions on Win OS? If anyone can suggest what might be happening it will be appreciated.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

What if you try to retrieve data in Python code?

Nothing at all. It runs, no error and goes back to prompt after a slight delay.

But does it fetch the data you just wrote?

Did you .commit()?

@KlausD. You cannot commit DDL statements, those are not executed in a transaction.

@user3146788 I don't think this has anything to do with windows ooerating system. Have you tried to use a try-catch construct to see if there are any sql errors along the way!

I did not do a try-catch yet but I will. I was not how to use in on a connect action only. I agree probbaly not a OS issue. I did not do .commit() because no where is this suggested as a need.

  host="localhost",
  user="user",
  password="pass",
  database="mydatabase"
)```          How can I get the error log when this command fails?

try using the command line tool and see what feedback you get , copy/paste EVERYTHING input/output from that session.

"When I run the script" -> how, exactly are you doing this?

I am running the script like this python text.py This this the point there is no feedback, no errors, nothing but back to a command prompt after a slight delay. It as if it hangs and but returns me back to prompt. I have recreated this on a remote Unix system and it works fine. I am at a loss. There is an note on Python / Mysql Connector Help page that has an * next to my version indicating that Python 3.13 uses a special certificate with mysql but I have no clue how to check or verify. Is there anyone who can duplicate the problem on a a windows box?

I still do not know why but this method works:
from mysql.connector import (connection)

cnx = connection.MySQLConnection(user='scott', password='password',
                                 host='127.0.0.1',
                                 database='employees')
cnx.close()

But this method does not:

import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='scott', password='password',
                              host='127.0.0.1',
                              database='employees')
cnx.close()

What puzzles me is that in the MYSQL Connector/Python developer guide it states that both work and that the first method is preferred, my luck of course.
Any ideas why, I would like to learn, fix and resolve.
Thanks,

lets check couple of things.
Did you call .commit()? For commands like CREATE DATABASE, the changes might not persist unless you  call mydb.commit() after mycursor.execute().
Enable MySQL Query Logging- To see if your queries are actually reaching MySQL, turn on general query logging in the my.ini file under [mysqld] with:
general_log = 1  
general_log_file = "mysql_query.log"  

Restart the MySQL service and check the log to debug.
Test with MySQL CLI: Try running the same SQL commands in the MySQL command-line tool to confirm it’s not a Python-specific issue.
Let me know if it works !
